# Manga/novel about a kid who is abandoned by his family for being weak, and later comes back in a mask and kills everyone

Tags: story-identification, novel, manga, cultivation

I'm looking for a manga, can't remember the title but the setting.

A kid, whose dad dies, was the head of the family, which was in decline. He is then abandoned by his family cause he's weak. He was meant to be married to a fellow member of the clan, but she mocks him.

He goes back later in the manga, masked, and reveals himself, and ends up killing everyone in the family.

It's killing me, but I can't remember the manga.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. Are the any sci-fi or fantasy (magical/supernatural) elements to this story? If not, then I'm afraid this question is off-topic here.

Comment: Hi, thank you. It was a cultivation/fantasy manga or novel.